# Build project that uses qt 4.8.5 in vs 2013?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to build project that uses qt 4.8.5 in vs 2013? I cant find qt Add In for qt 4.8.5  and vs 2013.

Comment: You need to build Qt by yourself. 4.x is not officially supported for msvc 2013 compiler.

Comment: @SaZ Do I understand correctly? 1. I need to compile qt by 2013 compiler 2. Use compiled dlls in vs 2013 project (Will "Qt5 add in"  work with 4.8.5? )

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes, but with some restrictions. It is prefferable to compile an addon by yourself (for Qt4).